# I cannot see my logs in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

```
Random rn = new Random();
Log.e("" , Integer.toString(rn.nextInt() % 20));
```

But in section logcat I see something else log

P.S. I just started learning , and don`t full understand how work in IDE

Comment: The `logcat` not only shows logs from your app, but the device in general issues its own logs. You can however, specify `logcat` to only show logs from your app's package.

Comment: How to do it? I
 try Log.e("rand" , Integer.toString(rn.nextInt() % 20));
End use filter, but did not help

Comment: You have to select a filter a the left side of your logcat console. If you don't you will see all the communication traffic form every application and the OS

Comment: in the filter box in the `android DDMS` tab within Android Studio you can just type in your application's package name there and it will filter for your app. For example `com.my.super.cool.app`

Comment: but it seems to me that the logs do not, I tried to use a search filter

Comment: and neither of them work to filter your package name?

Comment: glad it helped you out in some way.

Answer (score 1):

- Could you post here what you see in logcat?
- How are you running the app?

(I do not not have enough rep to comment on question).

You should see something like this:

```
04-22 18:25:32.446    1131-1131/com.your.app E/rand﹕ 19
```

When running the app, this should appear in red colour. Also make sure the search box (right of "log level" on picture) is empty and the text field next to it has "No filters".

[image: logcat window]